# Computing the null space of a bigmatrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, r-bigmemory, large-data

I can not find any function or package to calculate the null space or (QR decomposition) of a `bigmatrix` (from `library(bigmemory)`) in R. For example:

```
library(bigmemory)

a <- big.matrix(1000000, 1000, type='double', init=0)
```

I tried the following but got the errors shown. How can I find the null space of a `bigmemory` object?

```
a.qr <- Matrix::qr(a)
# Error in as.vector(data) : 
#   no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
q.null <- MASS::Null(a)
# Error in as.vector(data) : 
#   no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

Comment: Do any of these work `?qr`, or `?Matrix::qr`, or `?MASS::Null`

Comment: Yes. I do, but these functions don't work for a bigmatrix (S4 class) or I couldn't use them for big matrices. I can use these functions only for regular matrices, not for bigmatrices.

Comment: okay, I wasnt sure if you had a big <space> matrix or bigmatrix ;). Currently, your question is [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as it directly ask for a package recommendation, and in its present state it may get closed. But it is interesting. Could you edit your question with further details please. For example, could you add a small example of a bigmatrix (including any packages used), illustrate how standard tools dont work, and maybe ask for an alternative. Thanks

Comment: The [`bigalgebra`](https://github.com/kaneplusplus/bigalgebra/blob/master/R/bigalgebra.R) package has started some methods, but the QR functions are incomplete, however, this fork , https://github.com/cdeterman/bigalgebra , has added QR functionality. It does give a warning *Warning: This is not advised.* - you could ask author why

Comment: I have a bigmatrix. For example:                                        library(bigmemory)                                                                                      a<-big.matrix(1000000, 1000, type='double', init=5)                                                   
options(bigmemory.allow.dimnames=TRUE)                                         But I can not find its nullspace or QR decompostion. Thanks.

Comment: @Mahin Would a singular value decomposition suit you?

Comment: @Mahin Please see code and answer. 'RcppEigen' package supports QR and SVD and works with BigMemory.

Comment: @Technophobe01 Hello. Thank you very much for your guide. But I do not want to make a Linear Model Fitting. I just want to do a complete QR decomposition (or full SVD) of a big.matrix and then get into the null space of it. I run the 'RcppEigen' package but this package did not give me the QR decomposition of mat.obj and only gave the Linear Model Fitting. Thanks.

Comment: @F. Privé Yes, I really want to make a complete QR decomposition (or full SVD) of a big.matrix and then get into the null space of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to compute the full SVD of the matrix, you can use package **bigstatsr** to perform computations by block. A `FBM` stands for a Filebacked Big Matrix and is an object similar to a filebacked `big.matrix` object of package **bigmemory**.

```
library(bigstatsr)
options(bigstatsr.block.sizeGB = 0.5)

# Initialize FBM with random numbers
a <- FBM(1e6, 1e3)
big_apply(a, a.FUN = function(X, ind) {
  X[, ind] <- rnorm(nrow(X) * length(ind))
  NULL
}, a.combine = 'c')

# Compute t(a) * a
K <- big_crossprodSelf(a, big_scale(center = FALSE, scale = FALSE))

# Get v and d where a = u * d * t(v) the SVD of a
eig <- eigen(K[])
v <- eig$vectors
d <- sqrt(eig$values)

# Get u if you need it. It will be of the same size of u
# so that I store it as a FBM.
u <- FBM(nrow(a), ncol(a))
big_apply(u, a.FUN = function(X, ind, a, v, d) {
  X[ind, ] <- sweep(a[ind, ] %*% v, 2, d, "/")
  NULL
}, a.combine = 'c', block.size = 50e3, ind = rows_along(u),
a = a, v = v, d = d)

# Verification
ind <- sample(nrow(a), 1000)
all.equal(a[ind, ], tcrossprod(sweep(u[ind, ], 2, d, "*"), v))
```

This takes approximately 10 minutes on my computer.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, but I need to calculate the "full" SVD for an m×n matrix A (A=u.d.t(v)), where u is an m×m matrix, d is an m×n matrix and v is an n×n matrix. I really need the matrix v to get into the null space, but the matrix elements  get from your proposed method are different from what I want. For example see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771013/null-space-from-svd

Comment: @Mahin From my answer, you get `u` is m x n, `d` is diagonal n x n (here just the diagonal is given) and `v` is n x n like you want. It is full in the sense that you can perfectly reconstruct `a` from these 3 matrices.

Comment: @Mahin From what I understand, the full SVD that you talk about is just adding some (useless) columns to `u`. `v` should be the same and you can verify it by comparing `svd(mat)$v` and `svd(mat, nu = nrow(mat), nv = ncol(mat))$v` for any matrix with more rows than columns.

Comment: @ F. Privé You are right. I was wrong. In both cases, svd(mat)$v and svd(mat, nu = nrow(mat), nv = ncol(mat))$v, the matrix elements are the same, and I can now calculate the nullspace from v. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is it possible to have a 1e6x1e6 bigmatrix and to calculate its SVD by these commands in R, on your computer? I do not know how I can work for this size of matrix. Thanks.

Comment: @Mahin Here, this works because you have one dimension that is relatively small (1000).

Answer (score 2):

@Mahon @user20650 @F.Privė For clarity I pinged the bigmemory team and asked

> Essentially, is there an implementation of the QR function (QR Decomposition) that works with big memory matrixes?

I felt it useful to get clarity on the original question asked. @F.Privė - nice answer. Hopefully your answer, and their response will help guide people in the future. Their response below:

> Thanks for the note. There is not currently an implementation of the qr decomposition. Ideally, you would implement this using Householder reflections (if the matrix is dense) or Givens rotations (if it is sparse).
>
> The irlba package *is* compatible with bigmemory. It provides a truncated singular value decomposition. So, if your matrix is relatively sparse, you could truncate at the rank of the matrix. This is probably your best option. If you don't know the rank then you can use the package to update the truncation iteratively.
>
> Please note that if your matrix is (tall and skinny or short and fat) then the SO solution is OK. However, anytime you resort to calculating the cross-product you lose some numerical stability. This can be an issue if you are planning on inverting the matrix.

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for your guide. But I do not want to make a Linear Model Fitting.
 I just want to do a complete QR decomposition (or full SVD) of a big.matrix and then get into the null space of it. I run the 'RcppEigen' package but this package did not give me the QR decomposition of mat.obj and only gave the Linear Model Fitting. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks techno, useful comments. So the answer really is that there is no QR decomposition, or null space calculation out of the box, and so, c++ code will need to be written.

Comment: @user20650 - Yes, that is the current situation - unfortunate. Michael K. was super helpful here (A.k.a BigMemory). That said I do like the *F.Privė* alternate approach, a package I plan to take a look at in more detail.

Comment: @ techno Thanks for your attention. I'm currently doing the F.Privė's solution, but I hope that the relevant functions will soon be written.